# Azure Event Hub SAS token not expiring

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I've created an Azure Event Hub SAS token e.g.

```
let token =
    SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider.GetSharedAccessSignature(
        "{myPolicyName}",
        "{myPolicyKey}",
        "https://{serviceBusName}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubName}/publishers/{publisherName}",
        (TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)))
```

And then a connection string for the .NET SDK with it: -

```
let connectionString =
    ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder.CreateUsingSharedAccessSignature(
        Uri "sb://{serviceBusName}.servicebus.windows.net/",
        "{eventHubName}",
        "{publisherName}",
        token)
EventHubSender.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString).Send(myData)
```

However, even after the 5 seconds have elapsed, I am still able to send data using the token.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. SaS token based Authorization of Azure Service Bus Service doesn't support token life less than 5 Mins. Which means, Tokens are not guaranteed to expire before 5 mins. In general - clock skews across machines changes the dynamics of this Problem.

However, to achieve the above scenario, since you will have full control on Clock - you could issue a [RevokePublisher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.revokepublisher.aspx) call after 5secs - Which is effective immediately. All existing clients using that specific PublisherID will be closed by the Service.

One catch here is that - each revoke-publisher call will actually add an entry to the RevocationList of that eventhub. Each send call will do an optimal comparison against that list - so, be sure to Clean the revocationList regularly - which otherwise if grows very large, will impact EventHub send latency.

In this approach - remember that, you are using a 2nd access control knob - i.e., Publisher along with the first one - SaSToken. Whatever is the Token life - once you called a Revoke on a Publisher - all Send calls from that publisher will be rejected. Once, the token life expires - remove the removed Publisher (to clean up the RevocationList).

HTH!
Sree

Answer (score 0):

OK. It does expire, eventually - just not immediately after the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

SAS depends on clocks being in sync. If there are any differences between where you're generating timestamp and event hub, timing might not line up the way you expect it to.

As a workaround, sometimes people buffer SAS start/end by a short amount of time, to account for clock drift.